# Blender exporter GLTF Kronos Group glTD Specular Glossiness as Metalic Roughness

Tags: gltf

I'm trying to export Specular Glosiness Material but in exported file always get Metallic Roughness with empty values.

My setup for material "test"

[image]

result:

[image]

Using Blender 2.8 Beta:

[image]

What is correct approach?

Comment: Unfortunately the Spec/Gloss material export is not (yet?) supported in glTF-Blender-IO, which ships with Blender 2.80.  The node group shown in your screenshot is from the predecessor project, glTF-Blender-Exporter, and unfortunately has not been ported over to the new project.  Sorry!

Comment: Thank you ........